# What does it mean 'leaded' near junction-to-case resistance?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, heat, thermal

See in the picture below. On a separate note, why does some manufacturer specify both junction-to-case and junction-to-lead resistance?

[image]

On page 4 of this datasheet: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IDW10G65C5-DS-v02_02-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304339dcf4b10139fc597c6800fc

Comment: Can you link the datasheet from which you copied this image, please.

Comment: Why would you not specify both? Junction to case is only relevant for heatsinks and Junction to ambient is only relevant without heatsinks.

Comment: It's not junction-to-lead, it's junction-to-ambient for the leaded version of the component.

Comment: @Neil_UK The component only comes in one package, a 3-lead TO-247. There's no leadless version as far as I can tell. And if you're talking about leaded as in containing lead, it looks like it only comes in lead-free, so it's not that either.

Comment: @Hearth The device can be bought in other packages, e.g. as IDK10G65C5. I don't know why they decided to have separate datasheets though. I'm pretty sure this is a remnant from a common datasheet that existed at some point.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it's attached now

Comment: @DKNguyen I was saying junction to case/lead. what's the difference between these two

Comment: I don't know what leaded refers to but but the only things listed there are junction-ambient and junction-case. There is no junction-lead. Junction to ambient takes the the air interface into account. Junction-case does not (the heatsink is responsible for the air interface)

Answer (score 2):

Rthj-c is the thermal resistance from the junction to the component body/case and it remains unchanged irrespective of the external thermal arrangement that the designer would make.

[image: Thermal model of a TO package with a heat sink]

<sub>(Image source: [Infineon datasheet - Recommendations for board assembly of Infineon transistor outline type packages](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Recommendations_for_Board_Assembly_TO-P-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462580663ef0158069840880338))</sub>

Rthj-a indicates the thermal resistance from junction to air, including all interfaces from component case to air (thermal adhesive, heatsink etc.,).

But, Rthj-a specified in the datasheet refers to the thermal resistance from junction to air, when the component is not attached to a heat sink or any other heat dissipating material, but left open in air. Hence the higher value of Rthja.

[This Infineon application note](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN2018-07_CoolSiC_Automotive_Diode-ApplicationNotes-v01_10-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462689a790c0168c264c1d554d3) explains in detail all the specifications of Infineon SiC diodes. You may refer to section 3 to understand more about the thermal specification of the device.

Disclosure: I work for Infineon.

Comment: Infineon_employee - Welcome :) (a) Please read the [tour], the [help] and when you have time, the [Stack Exchange (SE) FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) to see details of the site rules & etiquette, which is different from typical forums. (b) When someone is affiliated with anything mentioned in an answer (link, image, text etc.) then [the affiliation must be disclosed](/help/promotion) in the text - implying it in the username is not enough. I added that for you this time. (c) When someone includes any content (text, image, photo etc.) copied or closely reworded etc. [...]

Comment: [...] from elsewhere, then [the original source must be referenced](/help/referencing). I found the image source and did that for you this time. || In future, please comply with the SE site rules including (i) disclosure of your affiliation (see the example I added in this answer) if you mention, include, or refer to Infineon or related companies in any way in an answer, to avoid any possible accusations of astroturfing / undisclosed promotion; and (ii) include a reference link for any material that you include in an answer, which was copied from elsewhere. Thanks and, again, welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to easily find out Infineon's test conditions for that datasheet parameter. Perhaps it is covered in some ancient standard. There does seem to be a lot of variation in quoted numbers for a similar overmolded TO-247-3 case (from 40°C/W to 62°C/W). Obviously there are some big differences in the measurement method and/or the leadframe itself. Generally, junction-to-ambient numbers are highly variable depending on actual conditions (especially for SMD parts) and the datasheet numbers should be verified in your application. Junction-to-case is a much more reliable number.

The "leaded" may be a vestigial option copied from datasheets that cover both SMD and leaded versions of semiconductors. For example [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IMZA65R083M1H-DataSheet-v02_00-EN.pdf) Infineon datasheet for a SiC MOSFET in the similar (one more lead) "PG-TO247-4-3" case.

[image]